# Instead of virtual keyboard black box appears and shifts the app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm a beginner with Xcode/Swift. I'm using Xcode 7.2.

I built an app that has functionality to bring up the keyboard when a textbox is clicked and remove the keyboard when somewhere else is clicked.

When I run my project in the simulator though, instead of the virtual keyboard appearing a black box appears at the top of the screen and shifts the app down. Clicking on any other text boxes causes the black box at the top of the screen to grow.

[image: App after a text field is selected]

I tried running iPhone5 through iPhone6Plus in the simulator and this happened with all of them. With iPhone4s the virtual keyboard popped up as intended, but all of the views became distorted.

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the code from the view controller if it helps:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var runningTimeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var strengthTimeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var runningCalTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var strengthCalTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodIntakeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bloodPressureTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var intakeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var caloriesBurnedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pressureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightChangeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightChangeLabel2: UILabel!

    var count : Int = 0

    var calc : calcModel = calcModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Initialize text boxes to 0
        runningTimeTextField.text = "0"
        strengthTimeTextField.text = "0"
        runningCalTextField.text = "0"
        strengthCalTextField.text = "0"
        foodIntakeTextField.text = "0"
        weightTextField.text = "0"
        bloodPressureTextField.text = "0"

        //Set report lablels to hidden
        self.intakeLabel.hidden=true
        self.caloriesBurnedLabel.hidden=true
        self.pressureLabel.hidden=true
        self.weightChangeLabel.hidden=true
        self.weightChangeLabel2.hidden=true


        //Added for keyboard stuff:
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);


        runningTimeTextField.delegate=self
        strengthTimeTextField.delegate=self
        runningCalTextField.delegate=self
        strengthCalTextField.delegate=self
        foodIntakeTextField.delegate=self
        weightTextField.delegate=self
        bloodPressureTextField.delegate=self

    }

    //Added for keyboard stuff:
    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 100
    }
    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += 100
    }

/*
    //Displays error that function is not overwritten.
    //Make the keyboard disapear as user touches outside the  text boxes
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>,withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        self.runningTimeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.strengthTimeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.runningCalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.strengthCalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.foodIntakeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.weightTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.bloodPressureTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
*/
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.runningTimeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.strengthTimeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.runningCalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.strengthCalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.foodIntakeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.weightTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.bloodPressureTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }


    @IBAction func submitPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        //Reveal output labels
        self.intakeLabel.hidden=false
        self.caloriesBurnedLabel.hidden=false
        self.pressureLabel.hidden=false
        self.weightChangeLabel.hidden=false
        self.weightChangeLabel2.hidden=false

        //Get input values
        let calBurnedRunning = Int(runningCalTextField.text!)
        let calBurnedStrength = Int(strengthCalTextField.text!)
        let intakeNum = Int(foodIntakeTextField.text!)
        let weight = Double(weightTextField.text!)
        let pressure = Double(bloodPressureTextField.text!)

        count++

        //Use calc model to calculate health report
        intakeLabel.text = String(calc.calculateCalories(intakeNum!, count: count))

        caloriesBurnedLabel.text = String(calc.calculateCaloriesBurned(calBurnedRunning!, calBurnedStrength: calBurnedStrength!, count: count))

        pressureLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", calc.calculateBloodPressure(pressure!, count: count))

        weightChangeLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", calc.weightChange(weight!, count: count))

         weightChangeLabel2.text = String(format: "%.2f", calc.weightChangeWeek(count))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.  One is this code:

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 100
}
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 100
}
```

You should not be messing with the frame of a view controllers view.

The other is this line:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This is causing the keyboard to be dismissed before it has a chance to appear.